# How to perform Weighted dimensionality reduction with Umap

Tags: python, dimensionality-reduction, runumap

The title pretty much says it all, I have a df with 40+ dimension which I'd like to process into the Umap algorithm in order to have a 2-d output.

I would like to know if it is possible to weight the input columns differently for the purpose of studying the possible different Umap outcomes.

Thank you for your time

P.S. I work in python

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to scale the input columns.  Your question is related to the subject of feature normalization, [discussed in the UMAP FAQ](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#should-i-normalise-my-features).  Is there any specific difficulty you're having while attempting to scale the inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply applying UMAP to `A`:

`A = X*W`

where `X` is your `Nx40` matrix and `W=diag(w)` is a `40x40` diagonal matrix of weights `w=[w1, w2,..., w40]`?

Consider using normalized weights `wi`, `i=1,2,...,40` such that `sum(w) == 1`, to distribute normally your information.